Mongoose .create function returning an error
Im trying to build a car selling website with MERN but while building the backed it sems that my .create function is not working even though the imports seem to be correct here is the error with the files:-
const newCar = await Car.create({
                              ^

TypeError: Car.create is not a function

here are the respective files:-
Car.js
const express= require('express');
const mongoose= require('mongoose');
const Car = require('../Models/Models.js');


const router = express.Router();

router.get ('/create', async function (req, res) {
     const newCar = await Car.create({
        name: "Porche",
          model: "911",
          color: "Blue",
          year: 1981,
          mileage: 500,
          price: 200000,
        })
         

})

module.exports = router;

index.js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const port = 3000
const car = require("./routes/Car");

app.use("/cars", car);

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

Models.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const carSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
  model: String,
  color: String,
  year: Number,
  mileage: Number,
  price: Number,
})

const UserSchema = new Schema({ 
name: String,
  email: { type: String, unique: true },
  password: String,
  cars: [carSchema],
  admin: Boolean,

})

const Car = mongoose.model('Car', carSchema)
const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)

module.exports = { Car, User };


You need to destructure your models from the Models.js export. Try const { Car } = require('../Models/Models.js'); in the Car.js file instead. You also might want to return a response in your router.get('/create' route handler callback.

this Worked thanks man if i could mark this answer as correct i would

This might be because the model has already been initialized in mongoose, this remains the cause until your server stops or restarts. When you call the car model for the first time it initialises the Model withing mongooses store of models so each time you call it it does this again which throws an error as there is already an existing model like within that running instance of mongoose  defined. The way to fix the issue with the models is to define it so that it's not created every time it's called,
in definition
const Car = mongoose.model('Car', carSchema) || mongoose.models.Car;
const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema) || mongoose.models.User;
Also try using the models like a class so instead of
await Car.create
try
const newCar = new Car({})
then end with
await newCar.save()
to save the model
